# Nikkor 18-55+55-200 lens vs 18-140mm lens?

Tags: lens

I know this question may have been asked before but i really need some advise according to my needs. Have finalized upon Nikon d5300 but not able to decide upon the lenses. Should i go for 18-55+55-200 or just 18-140? I need zoom because i will travel (not much) and would like to do macro photography or portraits. But not sure of the comfortability level while changing the lenses. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose the 18-140. The zoom gives you a better chance of catching a snapshot while traveling, without having to change the lens, and 140mm compared to 200mm is not that far apart, so you don't loose that much in terms of reach.

When it comes to macro photography, neither, without extension tubes or macro attachment lenses get you more then closeups shots.

As for portraits, 200mm on a crop sensor is a bit too tele for taking a portrait, requiring you to take quite a step back. So again, the difference between 140 and 200mm won't affect you that much. A fast prime however would be preferred for getting nicer bokeh.